# How to add text to ubuntu app indicator with with NW.js (or electron)?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, node-webkit, electron, nw.js

I know that it is possible to create a tray icon for a node-webkit application like so:

```
var tray = new gui.Tray({ title: 'Tray', icon: 'img/icon.png' });
```

but on Ubuntu the title won't be displayed. Is there anyway to achieve this?

I would like to use the tray icon to display dynamic information, which would be really annoying to do by changing the icon itself.

I would also be fine with using electron, if there is a way to implement it there.

EDIT:

For those interested in participating: I created some issues on [github for electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4742) and for [chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677333&can=2&q=Tray%20Title&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

Comment: Still no change on this on. If you want to change this, please upvote the electron issue linked above in the question and this new chrome issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1016125&can=2&q=Tray%20Title&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me with electron, [see this issue](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/430)

Electron 0.37.2., Ubuntu 15.10